# No Platform Toolset for selected MSBuild in jetbrains Rider

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, rider

I'm trying to open unreal C++ code in rider but doesn't work. I set the source code well on the rider but it does not recognize it as a compiler. Below are the pictures that show not even a simple `C++` project could be opened in the rider. I wrote this error: **No Platform Toolset for selected MSBuild** in jetbrains Rider in the title of the question, but if there is another problem, please help me how to open the C++ Unreal code in the rider.

[image]

[image]

[image]

More Information:

- **Unreal** version 4.27
- **Rider Integration** Plugin Version 1.4
- Click on Rider Link in IDE doesn't work for unknown reason.

[image]

Comment: Does the button `open settings and choose msbuild` work? Have you installed visual studio as suggested in one of the error messages?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for your comment, it was exactly the problem with MSbuild that was not installed on the system, I installed it and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

JetBrains Rider expects to find the C++ workload available in the MSBuild instance you are using. Make sure that you install one of the C++ workloads (Desktop development with C++, etc.) in the Visual Studio Installer.

Rider leverages MSVC to build C++ projects on Windows and supports only uproject and sln - based projects. You will need to use MSVC from VS/VS Build tools to build C++ projects on Windows.

Note that, if you are working on a general purpose cmake-based project, you might want to try CLion instead.